# monacaでウィジェットアプリが作成できますか？

Tags: monaca

時計アプリを作成し、デスクトップ上で動かしたいのですが、ウィジェットアプリの作成方法がわかりませんでした。
monocaで作成可能でしょうか？
可能な場合、方法を教えていただけますでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

Cordovaプラグインを自分で作成するか、どこかオープンソースなものをとってくればできると思います。

ですが、確かmonacaの場合、自作プラグインを使う場合は有料だったと記憶しています。